# Come and join us on the chat.

Tags: discussion, chat

Looking for fellow Musicians to chit-chat or perhaps do an interesting discussion with? Or do you want to help towards getting this site off the ground? Come and join us on the chat! :)

[image]

Feel free to leave a message, don't forget to star the room...

Answer (score 1):

3 years later ... and it's actually being used now!