# Looking for users interested in committing to the chat room(s)

Tags: discussion, chat

UPDATE: New trial-run room added, "Name that Tune"

To address:

1. Identifying the song stuck in your head.
2. Getting repertoire suggestions.
3. Identifying the song stuck in someone else's head.
4. Offering repertoire suggestions.

---

I'm looking for like-minded MP&T users to help grow our use of [The Practice Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) (our main chat room), [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium) (for posting recordings of oneself), [Saptak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132745/saptak) (for discussion of Indian classical music), and other site chat rooms, with the goal of increasing overall chatroom participation.

For example, I check in the the various chatrooms daily, and, at minimum, read what's been posted there. I also make a point of moving main-site comment threads I'm involved in to chat when appropriate, and I suggest off-topic but interesting questions be re-posted to chat. On the other hand, I'm not generally a conversation starter, and the few posts that happen each week (or month) aren't necessarily ones that spark my particular interests.

So I'm looking to encourage MP&T users to commit to checking out the room(s) monthly, weekly, or daily, respond to those topics that interest you, post conversation topics when so inclined, and generally encourage use of the chatrooms by suggesting them to posters and commenters on the main site and Meta.

To that end, I encourage like-minded users to "sign up" by adding your name to the comments. (Please include the statement "The chat rooms are [much better than *Cats*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFpZgDhS00U). I would use them again and again.") (No, don't really do that. I just like that sketch.)

A few related MP&T Meta posts:

- [Come and join us on the chat.](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/70803)
- [What happened to our chat?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/764/70803)
- [How do I notify others about chat room?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2530/70803)

Comment: I might be interested in it could be available for dvers to explain their actions, but doubtful whether an extra opportunity would be of any avail.

Comment: Maybe you can link to the new chatroom in the "update" to this post, too :)

Comment: I could be mistaken, but has the new chatroom been frozen and deleted?

Comment: @Namaskaram I believe so. I fell out of touch and didn't post to keep it open. But I think it's fair game when you or I or someone on the main site has an appropriate question to request to room be restored.

Comment: @Aaron Would you be able to give me a link to the chatroom, so that I can request that it be undeleted? I am unable to find it on my own.

Comment: @Namaskaram Actually, I can't find it either, which seems odd, since I created it. Anyway, I think you'll have to ask the mods directly. Try posting in the main chat room. Dr Mayhem checks it regularly, and Richard is also there frequently.

Answer (score 3):

> So I'm looking to encourage MP&T users to commit to checking out the room(s) monthly, weekly, or daily, respond to those topics that interest you, post conversation topics when so inclined, and generally encourage use of the chatrooms by suggesting them to posters and commenters on the main site and Meta.

Another suggestion I would like to add to the above is to make use of chat events (these can be one-time or recurring). Upcoming chat events are listed in a banner at the top of the list of all chat rooms, and curious users sometimes drop in to see what's going on. Previous experience with such events on a chat room linked to [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) suggests that more than a few users tend to stick around even after the event is done.

I believe moderators also have a tool to schedule events, which then appear in the community bulletin. I know that this is put to full use on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com), so one can take a look at how they do things to get an idea about how useful this tool could be on this site.

---

Here are some suggestions for chat events, as requested in the comments:

1. One simple idea is to have a recurring event, perhaps weekly, on a casual theme. A "hangout event for X" where X could be anything — Bach enthusiasts, cello enthusiasts, waltz music, etc.

   Since I haven't participated in [The Practice Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/440/the-practice-room), I can't really say anything more specific. But the idea is to choose a theme that is sufficiently broad that folks are tempted to drop in to see what's going on, and also allow them to chime in. It would help to choose a theme that the chat room regulars (or whoever chooses to host the event) are comfortable with, so that they can make easy conversation.
2. Since I also haven't participated in [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/126233/the-auditorium), I may be off the mark with my next suggestion. If the idea is to encourage more people to engage in the chat room by posting their recordings and start discussions around them, then it could help to have a recurring event (say, weekly) with a straightforward theme (e.g., "Weekly jam at The Auditorium. Feel free to share your tunes!" or any friendly open invitation of that kind). For one, it will reassure potential participants that they are not posting into the void if they know there's a chat event going on. For another, it lets people know that there is even such a venue on SE chat, and a recurring event will make it more likely that people won't forget that it exists.

   Again, since I haven't really participated in this chatroom, I may be wrong about what the purpose of the chatroom actually is, so feel free to correct me.
3. Another idea, to follow the lead of Literature, is to have month-long events, that are also promoted on the main site's community bulletin, based on any relevant theme. Suggestions can be collected in a Meta thread and voted on, and so on and so forth.

   For instance, if a classical composer was born in a particular month, then their works could be chosen as the theme for that month. The main chat room can host discussions on that composer's works. This could easily lead to new, good-quality questions being asked on the main site regarding that composer's works. A highlight reel can be promoted in a Meta thread at the conclusion of the event.

   Alternatively, current events can dictate which theme to pick.
   Another choice would be to look at under-represented tags on the main site and pick one of them in order to increase the number of views on the already existing questions and answers in that tag, as well as to promote new questions to be asked and answered.

At the end of the day, chat events make chat more lively, and this then promotes a sense of community.
Naturally, successfully promoting chat will require some dedication from the site's (and especially the chat's) users. As I see it, that is what the call to action in this thread is about. The details can be certainly refined through further discussion.

(Oh, and since I'm a room owner for [Saptak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/132745/saptak), I'll add that I have some plans (tentative, at the moment) to run chat events based on specific [ragams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raga), composers, and artists. The choice will have to depend on whatever I'm listening to and learning from at that time, at least initially. But this also means that it can be quite flexible, which I feel is a good thing.)

Comment: Can you give an example of a chat event that might make sense for MP&T?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Since I haven't participated in _The Practice Room_ and _The Auditorium_, my suggestions are necessarily generic, but I've updated the post with a few ideas.